# BCP BLOB exporting corrupted file

Tags: sql-server, blob, extract, bcp

I have looked thoroughly for an answer regarding BCP and extracting a BLOB from my SQL server database.  I have followed the various steps found in other threads and I keep coming up with the same file corrupted error.

My database has a column with data type IMAGE in BLOB format.  On the users end they can enter photos, pdfs, anything to this field and the server converts them to extremely long BLOBs. My task is to extract these so we can replace them with file name extensions, putting less stress on the database.

My current command is:

```
bcp "select notes_activex from myDatabase where NCR_NO = '1361'" queryout "C:\BCPtest\testOutput" -S -U -P -f C:\BCPtest\testOutput.fmt
```

My format file is correct for an image file as per some of the other files posted.  I have tried casting the image file first to a varbinary(max) and that still doesnt solve my solution.  No matter what I try I can get the BLOB to export but it is a corrupted file.

Added my format file:

```
11.0
1
1       SQLIMAGE            0       0       ""   1     notes_activex                  ""
```

Comment: Please post your format file. I'm guessing here, but maybe you didn't set the prefix length to zero in the format file.

Answer (score 2):

As far as binary data, BCP is intended for extracting data so that it can be later inserted into another SQL Server.  It's not saved in a format that's compatible with a binary data file.  You'll need to extract the data with a program or script, basically, that's capable of converting the data to bytes.

I've done this in the past with a PowerShell script.  I'd use something like the script below.  I strongly recommend determining the file from the SQL query if at all possible if you're fetching more than one record at a time.

```
# Define the connection parameters
$SqlServer = 'MyServerName';
$SqlDatabase = 'MyDatabase';
$SqlConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI' -f $SqlServer, $SqlDatabase;

# Define the query.  Note that one field is the file name and the other is the data.  
# Modify the WHERE clause to pull the records you need.  I am assuming that NCR_NO is not a unique identifier.
$SqlQuery = "select SomeUniqueID AS FileName, notes_activex AS FileData from myDatabase where NCR_NO = '1361'";

# Or use a GUID for the filename
# $SqlQuery = "select NEWID() AS FileName, notes_activex AS FileData from myDatabase";

# Define the path pattern for the output files.  {0} will get filled in with the filename.
$OutputFileFullNamePattern = 'C:\Path\To\Output\{0}';

# Create the Connection object and the Command object
$SqlConnection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $SqlConnectionString;
$SqlCommand = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand();
$SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlQuery;

# Open the connection
$SqlConnection.Open();

# Create the Sql Data Reader
$SqlDataReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while ($SqlDataReader.Read()) {
    # Set in the file name 
    $OutputFileFullName = $OutputFileFullNamePattern -f $SqlDataReader['FileName'];

    # Save the data to the file
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($OutputFileFullName,$SqlDataReader['FileData']);
}

# Close and dispose of the SQL connection
$SqlConnection.Close();
$SqlConnection.Dispose();
```

This uses an SqlDataReader, which loads records one at a time.  This means your system won't need to load the entire table into memory, but it does mean that you'll have a shared lock on the table until it's done if you're dumping the whole table.  If possible, run this query during downtime.

Comment: The table I am working with just has and identifier number and then the BLOB field in the database so unfortunately it is not possible to determine the file type beforehand.

Thank you for the response and help regarding this.

Comment: @CC09 But, the application has to know what the filename or file type is somewhere, right?  Maybe it's not in the myDatabase table, but it's got to be somewhere in the database.  You didn't seriously store arbitrary binary data with absolutely no metadata describing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I came into this database the way it is.  My boss was the one asking for this task.  There is no metadata describing its file type, just a ridiculously large BLOB in a field.

Comment: @CC09  The application itself doesn't even save *the name of the file*?  Like if you go into the application to access the BLOB, it doesn't tell you the filename or file type *at all*?  That's absurdly useless.  I mean, I guess you could dump the file data and try to use the [Linux `file` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) to try to determine the file type.  PDFs usually start with `%PDF-`, jpegs usually start with `ÿØÿà`.  That's a shot in the dark, though, and I bet .docx files would come up as .zip files (which they are) and so on.

Comment: The application is poor and lets the user upload whatever they want that doesn't save the file name :/.  We are slowly training people to use the new system which lets them upload files and the database holds the file location instead, which is why we want to extract all the BLOBs so we can clean up the database.

Comment: @CC09  Wow, that really sucks.  What I'd do is use the primary key for the table the file is in, or generate a GUID with `NEWID()` and use that (see my edited code above).  Then, yeah, I'd use the `file` command from Linux, [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)/[TrIDNet](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html), [JHOVE](http://jhove.openpreservation.org/) or something similar to determine the file types as best you can.

Comment: @CC09 Ouch... the first thing you *need* to do, is save the file name along with the BLOB. Otherwise saving whatever blob is nigh useless.

Comment: You can use the OA_methods to extract the file correctly. At least when it comes to signed dlls, the OA_methods seems to work just fine.